# Remove Leading 0 within plotmath expression using ggpubr in ggplot2 with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I would like to use the expression functionality within ggpubr to have both the ability to italicise my APA test statistics within text of a between groups comparison using `geom_bracket` within ggpubr.

My problem is that I need to remove the leading 0 that is produced, but this appears to be rendered not within the string (hence the second example where I show `gsub()` can't just pull it out.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

# Example close to what I currently have in code with leading 0 in-front of p value 
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len") +
 geom_bracket(
   xmin = "0.5", xmax = "1", y.position = 30,
   label = "list(~italic(t)(666)==6.66,~italic(p) < .05)", 
   type = "expression",
   tip.length = c(0.2, 0.02)
 )
 
# what i thought would work to use `gsub()` to remove what I don't want     
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len") +
 geom_bracket(
   xmin = "0.5", xmax = "1", y.position = 30,
   label = gsub(pattern = "p","q",  "list(~italic(t)(666)==6.66,~italic(p) < .05)"), 
   type = "expression",
   tip.length = c(0.2, 0.02)
 )

# but if you remove the zeros, they only come out of the text, not the leading 0 that is added
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len") +
 geom_bracket(
   xmin = "0.5", xmax = "1", y.position = 30,
   label = gsub(pattern = "0", "", "list(~italic(t)(666)==6.66,~italic(p) < .05)"), 
   type = "expression",
   tip.length = c(0.2, 0.02)
 )
```

Is there a way to either:

1. Have the ability to write both numbers, letters, and italics within an expression? I have tried this with using the "text" argument then using `italics()` but have not been able to get this to work. Could just be doing something silly after getting very frustrated with it.
2. Remove the leading 0 that is inserted using plotmath?

Either way, would be interested to know why the 0 is inserted anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plotmath expressions, the R parser converts any numbers found into actual numbers and will print them as actual numbers, leading zeros and all. If you want to avoid the leading 0, put `.05` in single quotes to identify it as a character string:

```r
ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len") +
 geom_bracket(
   xmin = "0.5", xmax = "1", y.position = 30,
   label = "list(~italic(t)(666)==6.66,~italic(p) < '.05')", 
   type = "expression",
   tip.length = c(0.2, 0.02)
 )
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

In the absence of reproducible data, I used the following sample data set, which has the relevant features that could be inferred from the question:

```r
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(dose = rep(c("0.5", "1"), each = 20), 
                 len = rnorm(40, rep(c(17.5, 20.5), each = 20),  3.5))
```